# MS Edge opens extra "Untitled" tab when viewing Excel file

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, microsoft-edge

in MS Edge an extra "Untitled" tab is opened when using:

```
window.open(excelFileUrl);
```

How can I prevent the additional tab? It does not happen in Chrome. See picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually appears when you have something being downloaded. I also have such additional tab when my URL points to a download link of a 3rd-party file provider. But I've avoided this tab by passing the `view.officeapps.live.com` link for the excel file.